# Angular frontend raises System.Nullable error without triggering the endpoint method in bakcend

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

In the development we design that user clicks a button and a POST request will be sent to backend. The endpoint method will then be called and create a new entry in the database. Afterwards the created instance will be returned by the same endpoint method using `CreateAtRoute()` function. The method is as follows.

```
/// <summary>
/// api/designer
/// </summary>
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUniqueAsync([FromBody] UniqueIdDto id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await _checklistService.CreateUniqueIdAsync(id, cancellationToken);
        if (response)
        {
            return CreatedAtRoute("UniqueByDs", new { uniqueDs = id.DSNumber, targerProject = id.Project, loopID = id.Loop }, id);
        }
        return BadRequest("Unique number is not created");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The structure of UniqueIdDto is:

```
public class UniqueIdDto
{
    public string? DSNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Issue { get; set; }
    public string? Task { get; set; }
    public string? Project { get; set; }
    public string? User { get; set; }
    public int? Loop { get; set; }
}
```

Normally the returned value contains the a url with parameter in the header inside the **Location** key. The frontend is then supposed to receive the 201 response and get the value of **Location** key. Then the frontend send a GET request to the new endpoint. In the backend the method is like

```
    /// <summary>
    /// api/designer/UniqueByDs?uniqueDs=[value1]Full&targetProject=[value2]&loopID=[value3]
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet("UniqueByDs", Name = "UniqueByDs")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetChecklistByUniqueNumberAsync([FromQuery] string uniqueDs, [FromQuery] string targetProject, [FromQuery] string loopID, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var checklist = await _checklistService.GetChecklistByUniqueNumberAsync(uniqueDs, targetProject, loopID, cancellationToken);
            if (checklist != null)
            {
                return Ok(new { data = checklist });
            }
            return BadRequest(checklist);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But when we launch the project and click the button in browser, nothing happens to the backend and the endpoint method is not triggered. In the browser we see error messages:
[image: Error message]

The code which throws error is like:

```
CreateorLoadDQCtable() :void {
    if (this.selectedDsNumber != null && this.selectedIssue!= null && this.selectedTask!= null) {
      this.loadDqcTable = true
      console.log("step1")
      const userEnteredData = {
        "dsNumber": this.selectedDsNumber,
        "issue": this.selectedIssue,
        "task": this.selectedTask,
        "project": this.selectedProject,
        "user":this.userName,
        "loop": this.selectedLoop
      };
      console.log("step2")
      this.desginerService.postProjectAndDsNums(userEnteredData).subscribe({
        next:(dqctableUrl) => {
          if (typeof dqctableUrl === 'string' && dqctableUrl) {
            console.log(dqctableUrl)
            this.desginerService.getDqcTableDataFromUrl(dqctableUrl).subscribe(response => {
              if (response.status === 200){
                this.DqcTableList = (<any>response.body).data.map((item: DqcCode) => ({
                  ...item,
                  designerSelections: item.designerValidation ? item.designerValidation.split(';') : [],
                  checkerSelections: item.checkerValidation ? item.checkerValidation.split(';') : [],
                }));
                
                if (this.selectedLoop === "Loop-2"){
                  this.showLoop2Validations = true;

                }else if(this.selectedLoop === "Loop-3") {
                  this.showLoop2Validations = true;
                  this.showLoop3Validations = true
                }
                console.log(this.DqcTableList);
              }
              
            })
          }
          
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error('Error fetching data from new URL:', error);
        }
      })

      
    } else {
      let message = 'The following selections are missing: ';
      let missing = [];
      if (this.selectedDsNumber == null) missing.push('DS Number');
      if (this.selectedIssue == null) missing.push('Issue');
      if (this.selectedTask == null) missing.push('Task');

      alert(message + missing.join(', '));
    }
    
    
  }
```

```
  postProjectAndDsNums(data: any):Observable<string | null> {
//error happens here
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/api/designer', data, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        
        if (response.status === 201) {

          const newUrl = response.headers.get('Location');
          console.log(newUrl)
          if (!newUrl) {
            alert("Unable to Load Dqc table for the current data entry");
            throw new Error('URL header not found');
          }
          return newUrl;
        } else if (response.status === 500)  {
          alert("DS Number already exists");
          return null;
        }
        alert("An unexpected error occurred");
        return null;
       
      })
    );
  }
```

I have checked in my backend and do not find a class with property "id" in it. I am not sure if I developed the backend incorrectly or the frontend code has some bugs.

Could someone help to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error text directly tells you that the value of `this.selectedLoop` can't be converted to target type Nullable. I bet you send an empty string instead of expected `null` or integer value.

In order not to have this kind of issues in future, I highly recommend you to use, for example, Swashbuckle  to generate TS contracts and then use these contracts in your Angular code. Angular compiler will immediately show you an error if you try to assign potentially not compatible values.

Comment: You are right. `this.selectedLoop` returns a string with some letters but in backend it is defined as int. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should pass object instead of JSON here

**Change this....**

```
const userEnteredData = {
    "dsNumber": this.selectedDsNumber,
    "issue": this.selectedIssue,
    "task": this.selectedTask,
    "project": this.selectedProject,
    "user":this.userName,
    "loop": this.selectedLoop
};
```

**to this....**

```
const userEnteredData = {
    dsNumber: this.selectedDsNumber,
    issue: this.selectedIssue,
    task: this.selectedTask,
    project: this.selectedProject,
    user:this.userName,
    loop: this.selectedLoop
};
```

Not pretty sure about this but this may be a reason.